# why json failed to load the json_file on the second time

Tags: json, python-3.5

the test code is following:

```
import json

with open('./reports/jsonDumps/testResult.json') as behave_json:
    print("helloxxxxx", behave_json, "\n")
    print(json.load(behave_json))
    print("helloxxxxx", behave_json, "\n")
    print(json.load(behave_json))
```

I try it on the same "with scope", but it meet error

Comment: {
"investorId": "5b6175a8fb78cf6b741e660b",
"accountId": "5b6175a8fb78cf6b741e660d",
"investmentId": "5b72de59fb78cf65023bd0e9",
"balance": 4000000,
"amount": 500000
}

Comment: helloxxxxx <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./test.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> 

{'balance': 4000000, 'accountId': '5b6175a8fb78cf6b741e660d', 'amount': 500000, 'investmentId': '5b72de59fb78cf65023bd0e9', 'investorId': '5b6175a8fb78cf6b741e660b'}
helloxxxxx <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./test.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    //...//
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)